# Loading XAML in run time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to load a particular piece of XAML code in runtime.
Using the below code, I can load the xaml present in a txt file.

```
private void btnLoadXAML_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {

    string LoadedFileName = @"C:\test\sample.txt";

    //Load the file
    FileStream Fs = new FileStream(@LoadedFileName, FileMode.Open);
    Grid grdToLoad = new Grid();
    grdToLoad.Height = 210;
    grdToLoad.Width = 400;

    grdToLoad = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(Fs) as Grid;

    grdLoadXAML.Children.Add(grdToLoad);

    Fs.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
}
```

The above code will actually create a new Grid control and load the XAML present in the text file and create the controls as per the code.
Consider the below code...

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title=" " 
    Height="270" 
    Width="420" 
    Background="{x:Null}" 
    Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" 
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize" 
    WindowStyle="None" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d">
```

The above is the "Window" tag. I just need a couple of properties of it in run time. For eg: the below code

```
WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

I don't want the above to hard code in the xaml but to insert it in run time, how can I do that? I tried the method I mentioned initially but I get run time error.

Comment: Do you want to access the Window class that contains your dynamic grid?

Comment: This can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768261/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-share-resources-between-usercontrols-in-a-wpf-user-co?rq=1 (yes, you can load dictionary in runtime. i just wanted to give a way)

Comment: Hi.. I suppose there will be only one window tag with x:Class attribute?

Answer (score 0):

XAML loaded through `XamlReader` has some restrictions compared to normal compiled XAML files, including not depending on code-behind, since it is just parsing rather than compiling. In your case the Window you're trying to use has the usual `x:Class` attribute which specifies its code-behind component. If you're just using it to load some properties you should be able to strip that attribute out, either from the saved file or by using `File.ReadAllText` and `XamlReader.Parse` to modify at runtime.